# How to remove right side space in TextWrangler?

Tags: macos, text-editor, bbedit

In TextWrangler, I have a lot of white area in the editor that goes right well past 100 characters. Then it continues into this gray area. That creates a huge horizontal scroll bar.

I really only need it to about 85 characters to the right. Is there any way to restrict this?

Comment: Also, BBEdit is now free for all, so you’ll want to move to that over TW when it’s convenient for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Text Wrap

You can enable **Text Wrap** to have the text soft wrap and avoid the horizontal scroll bar. Use the menu item:

View (menu) > Text Display > Soft Wrap Text

See Ryan Rampersad's [Text Wrapping in TextWrangler](http://chronicles.blog.ryanrampersad.com/2011/10/text-wrapping-in-textwrangler/) for more details about this feature.

[image: Text Wrangler - Soft Wrap Text]